# Randomly loosing power to all USB ports than forced to reboot

Tags: usb, 64-bit, power

This is going on since about 2 months now. 
A wrong mouse move and everything stops. All USB ports loose power.

My first thought was acceleration , or combo between Skype and Adobe Suite. Wrong. 
Changed wireless mouse many time. Changed MX 5500 set twice.
Changed the order of devices connected to USB's
Made sure no bad drivers are there
[image: http://prntscr.com/4d0lx9]
Made sure the USB "go to sleep" settings are disabled.

Specs:

- Icon Xeon starter server - 4 U SuperMicro server chassis with 850W AC
  power supply (cooling redundant) and low noise Ian speed control.
- 2 x 8cm Hotswappable PWM cooling fans.  I 9mm rear exhaust Ian.  2\
- Active heatsink w/healpipe. SuperMicro extended Motherboard with RAID
  feature .  Model X8DA3
  http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DA3.cfm
- BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 2.1, 8/12/2011 SMBIOS
- Version 2.6 32 Gigs of Dual Channel DDR3 1333 ram (4 x 8 gigs each)
- Nvidia GForce GTX580
- Windows 7 Ultimate.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

The funny thing is that there are no errors before restart
[image]

all I can see is the error when I restarted the system.

Comment: Have you run any diagnostics? Is there updated BIOS available? Is the unit properly grounded?

Comment: What was the clue you had to them actually loosing the power itself, and not "dropping out" which may have many lights go out, but does not define an actual power issue?  What all USB items do you have connected, I assume from your post there are no high power consuming items at all?   You are in device manager there, do you observe the items dropping out there (if show hidden devices is on becomming ghosted items)?  Are you charging a phone or running a usb powered disk item?  How well cooled would you say the Motherboard itself is (as in the components not the cpu or chipsets)?

Comment: Why is there shown a VIA usb item? when I do not see any via chipset items in the specs?  Look Inside the Hubs and controllers for the "driver details", there are things that can get in there, that might not help. I realise you already did drivers, but who knows?

Comment: @CharlieRB the only BIOS version that they show on their site is same as the one installed.

Comment: @Psycogeek I have 1 seagate external hard drive, MX 5500 Logitec set

Comment: Sudden stops with no log entries is almost always a hardware issue. Test your RAM for a few days, test your drives, etc.